# Prove why the shock equation is not linear.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**I need a hint not an answer before answering this question:**

Two part question:

The homogeneous shock equation is given by $u_x$ + $u$$u_y$ = 0

Part 1) Show why the shock equation is not linear.
Part 2) Which linearity is the shock equation. (I get it's not linear, but it's not completely non linear).

The definition of linearity is:
L(u+v) = L(u) + L(v)
c* L(u) = L(c*u)
I'm not sure what our operator is. Is it the derivative? Our operator is L but I don't know what our linear operator is. I can't see why this isn't linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $Lu = u_x + u u_y$, hence:

$$L(a u + b v ) = a u_x + b v_x + (a u + b v) \, (au_y + bv_y)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I can, but what's the operator? That's where I'm more confused at.

Comment: @KagamineLen I think what is confusing you is that you seem to think that the operator can't have multiple appearances of the thing it operates on but that's not the case. In this particular problem, think of the operator as $$L\cdot = (\cdot)_x + (\cdot)(\cdot)_y$$ where $\cdot$ is a placeholder for what the operator is supposed to act on.

Comment: +1. I like your answer better than mine, so I'm removing mine.

Comment: I feel like I need to ask this. Should I review ODES and Linear Algebra before PDES. I got an A in odes and remember almost everything from the class.

Comment: Thanks, wltrup. @KagamineLen, perhaps you want to address that question in http://academia.stackexchange.com/ Cheers!